# Ubuntu 12.02 32 bit printer program executable file cannot run properly in ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, virtual-printer

Ubuntu 12.02 32 bit printer program executable file cannot run properly in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit I installed bellow three library packages but it's not working.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
./example32bitprogram**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
dpkg --print-architecture
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two plausible **major** reasons for it not working:

1. Software created for an older version of an OS, and you're trying
   to run it under a newer version, where the new OS has had numerous changes applied.
2. On top of that the software intended for the 32bit version of the
   OS, and are trying to run it under the 64bit version of the OS.

I'd say this is a situation where the software **MIGHT** run (given the right conditions), but that cannot be guaranteed.

Adding the first level of dependencies might not be enough, there might be **a number** of subsequent (levels of) dependencies.